# Get raw value of attribute in js

Tags: javascript, attributes, raw

Here is sample code:

```
<div id="file" filename="/blahblah-&#1633;.php">AA</div>
<script>
var d = document.getElementById('file').getAttribute('filename');
console.log(d);
</script>
```

I want to get:
`/blahblah-&#1633;.php`
in logs, but above entity is translated to unicode.
How to get raw value of attribute in js or jquery?

Comment: what do you mean unicode? can you post it?

Comment: /blahblah-١.php

Comment: can you explain for what propose?

Comment: I want to post this field in ajax request. In filesystem this filename, is as above with entity, but js changes it and script on second end of request fails.

Comment: Can you print the result of the backend side too?

Comment: File not found.

Answer (score 0):

When html file is generated via php, need to escape strings, especially this:
`htmlspecialchars('/blahblah-&#1633;.php');`
In my case it was generated by php.